# Can anyone tell me the form of the verb in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

In the sentence: "A series of events happened, each caused by the previous one."

I want to know the form of the verb "caused"? (tense, voice, ...)

Comment: Past tense: caused.

Comment: Is it active or passive voice?

Comment: Passive, as used in your sentence.

Comment: @user070221 Is it OK that there isn't "was" before "caused"? Shouldn't it be "was caused"?

Comment: It is a standard use for the transitive verb 'cause' as a past participle. Participles are used after nouns (pronouns) in order to define or identify the nouns mentioned, in the same way as identifying relative clauses. ...each caused by ...= … each was caused by...

Comment: Your sentence is fine. "Caused" is a past participle in a passive clause. The word that "each" determines is ellipted, but we understand "each one". Ellipting the first "one" avoids the somewhat inelegant repetition of "one"